# How to expand the height of li inside vertically centered div?

Tags: html, css

I have `ul` that is vertically centered. I would like to expand the height of `li` to be the same height of `div.wrapper` so that on hover, the entire height of `li` is covered with the background colour. Currently it only covers the width of the `li`.

```css
.wrapper {
    display:table;
    height:8em;
    background-color:#004857;
    width:100%;
}
.inner {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
ul.list {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    width:50%;
    margin:auto;
    height:100%;
}
ul.list li {
    float:left;
    width:5em;
    text-align:center;
}
ul.list li a {
    color: #fff;
    display:block;
}
ul.list li a:hover {
    background-color: #ff5500;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="inner">
        <ul class="list">
            <li><a href="#">One</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Two</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Three</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/462/

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    display:table;
    height:8em;
    background-color:#004857;
    width:100%;
}
.inner {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
ul.list {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    width:50%;
    margin:auto;
    height:100%;
}
ul.list li {
    float:left;
    width:5em;
    height:inherit; //added
    text-align:center;
}
ul.list li a {
    color: #fff;
    display:block;
    padding:4em 0;//added
}
ul.list li a:hover {
    background-color: #ff5500;
}
```

Comment: Good solution. But you didn´t add the `display:block;` in `ul.list li a`. It was there before. ;) Another possible solution is to add ``line-height: 8em; to ul.list li`` and `height:100%; to ul.list li a ` like [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/463/)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Yeah this is also another way of doing the same.

Comment: @DerVampyr: have tried your solution and added it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Currently you're only using the float option (:hover) on the anchor. The anchor is the element that changes background color, not the div.

You could try to expand the size of the anchor (a) in the css. This anchor is still default in size.

Answer (score 0):

try this

[**DEMO FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/68hcje3m/)

```
ul.list li {
    float:left;
    width:5em;
   line-height: 8em; //added
    text-align:center;
}
ul.list li a {
    color: #fff;
    display:block;
    height:100%; //added
}
```

tried
@Der Vampyr's comment

> Another possible solution is to add line-height: 8em; to ul.list li
>   and height:100%;

Answer (score -2):

Add `height: 100%;` to both `ul.list li` and `ul.list li a`.

Comment: Not enough. You need something that pushes the height of the a tag, like a padding e.g.